# I am having trouble using contains in sql server 2008 and doesn't show any output if my text has "for" or "c#"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table with one of the columns as event_name which has value/data "C# for Beginners" in that column. I am trying to search using contains keyword as:

```
select * from events where company_id = 1 and contains(event_name, '"for"')
```

but it doesn't return anything. I also tried to query as

```
select * from events where company_id = 1 and contains(event_name, '"c#"')
```

and it doesn't work either (no data in output). But when I modify my query as

```
select * from events where company_id = 1 and contains(event_name, '"beginners"')

or
select * from events where company_id = 1 and contains(event_name, '"c#*"'),
```

It gives me expected output.

I then tried:

```
select * from events where company_id = 1 and contains(event_name, '"for*"')
```

but it is not working

I am not understanding why it is failing when I use "for" or "c#" in contains.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"for" is a stopword in English, so it won't be indexed into full-text index. If you want to search records contains specific string, use `LIKE` operator

```
select * from events where company_id = 1 and event_name LIKE '%for%'
```

You can view all stopwords for English by run following query

```
SELECT  stopword
FROM    sys.fulltext_system_stopwords ssw
WHERE   language_id = 1033
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell why it if failing if I give text as "C#" and not failing when text is "C#*"?

Comment: @chaitanya In my test, "C#" works as expected. I don't know why it's not working on your side.